# A vertical multilevel menu which adjusts to screen

Tags: css

I have seen many vertical multilevel menus, but all of them goes below the screen bottom if they lie near the screen bottom. I want them move up instead of going down just like tool tips work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can help you.

[Solution For Very Long Dropdown Menus](http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/)